# How to get default open yum client's /etc/yum.repos.d configuration

Tags: linux, yum, centos6

All , Since my server install yum client and config the  /etc/yum.repos.d as our private yum repo , So I only can yum install our private rpm packages and software , Now I want to change it to point to common open public repos for installing the common rpm packages , How do I re-set the yum repo configuration ? If you have command like "lynx -dump "xxxx" > /etc/yum.repos.d " will be better , Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to create additional repo in /etc/yum.repos.d

Delete local repo for /etc/yum.repos.d/

following is the syntax

```
eg  /etc/yum.repos.d/public.repo

[name-name]
name=newpublicrepo
baseurl=http://publicurlof repo
enabled=1
gpgcheck = 0
```

or you can install rpmforge, epel from net directly.

http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge